# Prediction with LSTM using Keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, array-broadcasting

I am predicting Y based on X from past values. Our formatted [CSV dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vO62n7GolfvCOHLkPEmc1VLwrV6iPc5n) has three columns (time_stamp, X and Y - where Y is the actual value) whose sample format is

```
time,X,Y
0.000561,0,10
0.000584,0,10
0.040411,5,10
0.040437,10,10
0.041638,12,10
0.041668,14,10
0.041895,15,10
0.041906,19,10
 ... ... ...
```

Before training the prediction model, here is how the plots of X and Y respectively look like the following.

[image]

[image]

Here is how I approached the problem with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks in Python with Keras.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


np.random.seed(7)

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('test32_C_data.csv')
n_features = 100


def create_sequences(data, window=15, step=1, prediction_distance=15):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(0, len(data) - window - prediction_distance, step):
        x.append(data[i:i + window])
        y.append(data[i + window + prediction_distance][1])

    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)

    return x, y


# Scaling prior to splitting
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:, ["X", "Y"]].values)

# Build sequences
x_sequence, y_sequence = create_sequences(scaled_data)

# Create test/train split
test_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.90)
valid_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.90)
train_end = len(x_sequence) - (test_len + valid_len)
x_train, y_train = x_sequence[:train_end], y_sequence[:train_end]
x_valid, y_valid = x_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len], y_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len]
x_test, y_test = x_sequence[train_end + valid_len:], y_sequence[train_end + valid_len:]

# Initialising the RNN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layerand the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(15, input_shape=(15, 2)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

# Getting the predicted values
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
#y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)

plot_colors = ['#332288', '#3cb44b']

# Plot the results
pd.DataFrame({"Actual": y_test, "Predicted": np.squeeze(y_pred)}).plot(color=plot_colors)
plt.xlabel('Time [Index]')
plt.ylabel('Values')
```

Finally, when I run the code - the neural model seems to capture the pattern of the signal well as it is shown below.

[image]

However, one problem that I encountered in this output is the ranges of Y. As it is shown in the first two plots, the ranges should be 0-400 as shown above and to solve that I tried to use the scaler to `inverse_transform` as `y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)` but this throws an error: `ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (7625,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (7625,2)`. How can we solve this `broadcast shape` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the scaler has remembered that it was fed 2 features(/columns). So it is expecting 2 features to invert the transformation.

Two options here.

1) You make two different scalers: `scaler_x` and `scaler_y` like this :

```
# Scaling prior to splitting
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))

scaled_x = scaler_x.fit_transform(df.loc[:, "X"].reshape([-1, 1]))
scaled_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(df.loc[:, "Y"].reshape([-1, 1]))

scaled_data = np.column_stack((scaled_x, scaled_y))
```

Then you will be able to do :

```
y_pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

2) You fake the X column in your output like this :

```
y_pred_reshaped = np.zeros((len(y_pred), 2))
y_pred_reshaped[:,1] = y_pred
y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_reshaped)[:,1]
```

Does that help?

## EDIT

here is the full code as required

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


np.random.seed(7)

# Load data
#df = pd.read_csv('test32_C_data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(100,3)), columns = ['time', 'X', 'Y'])
n_features = 100


def create_sequences(data, window=15, step=1, prediction_distance=15):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(0, len(data) - window - prediction_distance, step):
        x.append(data[i:i + window])
        y.append(data[i + window + prediction_distance][1])

    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)

    return x, y


# Scaling prior to splitting
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))

scaled_x = scaler_x.fit_transform(df.loc[:, "X"].reshape([-1,1]))
scaled_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(df.loc[:, "Y"].reshape([-1,1]))

scaled_data = np.column_stack((scaled_x, scaled_y))

# Build sequences
x_sequence, y_sequence = create_sequences(scaled_data)

test_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.90)
valid_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.90)
train_end = len(x_sequence) - (test_len + valid_len)
x_train, y_train = x_sequence[:train_end], y_sequence[:train_end]
x_valid, y_valid = x_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len], y_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len]
x_test, y_test = x_sequence[train_end + valid_len:], y_sequence[train_end + valid_len:]

# Initialising the RNN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layerand the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(15, input_shape=(15, 2)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

# Getting the predicted values
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Comment: Does it say at which line the error occurs? May it be that you need to do y_pred_reshaped[:,1] = y_pred[:,0] ?  I will try to clarify the point 1

Comment: Ok Option 1 is tested and works on my machine... Is it ok ?

Comment: done :-) When you mention an error, try to give the line where it occurs, it's very difficult to get any meaningful information out of it otherwise.

Comment: Seems quite straightforward.... add : y_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_test) before plotting...